# Is it possible to relocate pythonbrew

Tags: debian, packaging, pythonbrew

I am trying to create a debian package containing customly built python using pythonbrew.

The compilation and debian construction is successfull. 
The problem is that when I install the package on other machine some modules does not work. For example `hashlib` or even `os.getcwd()` is not working. Whereas on build machine everything works.

Is it possible to relocate python installation? What might be the problem?

```
>>> from hashlib import md5
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/sw-python/extra/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/opt/sw-python/extra/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/sw-python/extra/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/opt/sw-python/extra/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/sw-python/extra/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/opt/sw-python/extra/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/sw-python/extra/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/opt/sw-python/extra/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/sw-python/extra/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/opt/sw-python/extra/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/sw-python/extra/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/opt/sw-python/extra/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name md5
```

I build it in `/opt/sw-python/extra/pythonbrew` directory and on install pythonbrew is placed to the same `/opt/sw-python/extra/pythonbrew` directory.

Target machine:

```
Linux german-pc 3.0.0-12-generic ... x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Build machine:

```
Linux ds5vs5 2.6.32-5-amd64 ... 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I installed my debian package on a different Debian machine similar to build machine. And it worked!

I don't know what exactly caused the problem, but I guess it's a difference in kernel or compiler.